# How to iterate fastutil hashmap in Java8?

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

In `Java8`, want to compare time performance and memory consumption of `Int2ObjectOpenHashMap` (`fastutil` library) and `HashMap<Integer, MyObj>` in my app. Previously I iterated java standard hashmap as below:

```
HashMap<Integer, MyObj> myobjs = new HashMap<Integer, MyObj>();
// fill myobjs in
for (Map.Entry<Integer, MyObj> obj : myobjs.entrySet()) {
    ...
}
```

How can I iterate (in the fastest possible way) the `Int2ObjectOpenHashMap`?

Answer (score 4):

There is the specialized `fastForEach()` on the entry set, which, to gain extra performance, instead of recreating an entry instance for every loop cycle, reuses the entry instance of type `Int2ObjectMap.Entry<MyObj>`:

```
Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<MyObj> int2ObjHashMap = ...;
int2ObjHashMap.int2ObjectEntrySet().fastForEach((Int2ObjectMap.Entry<MyObj> entry) -> {
    int key = entry.getIntKey();
    MyObj value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
});
```

By using the int-specific methods `int2ObjectEntrySet()` and `getIntKey()` instead of `entrySet()` and `getKey()`, this code also avoids the unnecessary inboxing and outboxing of the entry's key to/from `int` and `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use streams and lambda expressions ,

```
Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<Integer> myobjs = new Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<Integer>() ;
myobjs.forEach((key,value)->{
    int key1 =key;
    MyObj obj = value;
});
myobjs.entrySet().forEach(x->{
    int key = x.getKey();
    MyObj obj =x.getValue();
});
myobjs.entrySet().stream().forEach(x->{
    int key = x.getKey();
    MyObj obj = x.getValue();
});e
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Int2ObjectOpenHashMap<MyObj> myobjs = // ...
for(Int2ObjectMap.Entry<MyObj> entry : myobjs.int2ObjectEntrySet()) {
    int key = entry.getIntKey();
    MyObj obj = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Int2ObjectOpenHashMap` also implements `entrySet()`, so you iterate in the same way.